# Async setState()

Tags: flutter, dart

Я хочу добавить в своё приложение async функцию, которая будет постоянно работать параллельно с текущей отрисовкой и после каждого и после каждого изменения вызывать setState() чтобы, например, обновить список виджетов, через определенные промежутки времени, например так:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:quiver/time.dart';
import 'dart:io';    
void main() {
      runApp(AttryApp());
    }

    class AttryApp extends StatelessWidget{
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: HomePage(),
        );
      }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{

      @override
      _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>{

      List<Widget> currentMessages = [];

      Future<void> addText() async {
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
          setState((){
            currentMessages.add(Text("It works?"));
          });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        addText();

        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: ListView(
              children: (currentMessages.isEmpty ? <Widget>[Container()]:currentMessages),
            ),
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

Но это не работает, т.е, я предполагаю, что setState() просто не делает повторного вызова функций. Также я пробовал рекурсивно в addText() вызывать addText(), что также не дало результата.

Comment: Пробовал даже while true в этой async функции, что также не сработало

Comment: @Pudberg разобрались? если нет, завтра напишу ответ утром

Comment: Замените `ListView` на `Column` или используйте `ListView.builder` и реализуйте у него `itemCount` и `itemBuilder`